# db.repairDatabase() did not reduce size of database

Tags: mongodb

I have a db that is about 8G.
I did copy db to generate a copy.
Then I pruned the copy using js console.
Then I ran a reapir DB and the copy is still the exact size as the original.

Comment: What do you mean by pruned? We need more information maybe a `stats()`?

Comment: i mean I deleted alot of data. according to stats the db is only 2G (dataSize = 2G)

Comment: Can you show us this output, directly from the console? This is odd because even with pre-alloc the DB should be more like 4GB for on-disk size then. Also show us `show dbs` output. Try a `mongod` restart too and tell us if anything changes, I think those figures might be held in RAM

Comment: I just recreated from scratch and recorded the output. I restarted mono and got the same size
https://gist.github.com/thedug/4dbfa2e1ac84c88cd789

Comment: just to clarify - which database did you delete data from?  and how much?

Comment: I deleted from the copy. I'm not sure but I believe I deleted quite a bit. I was trying to us show dbs to see how much.. Is there another way to tell?

Comment: Nah the db.stats shows you did that, the reason I have not really answered is because I am really unsure why show dbs shows that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood, this means that you did not free up enough space to return an entire extent or file to the OS.  Imagine that you have five 2GB files (MongoDB preallocates files in 2GB increments after the first few smaller files) and now imagine that you had 8GB of data in this DB.  The last file will always be empty because MongoDB preallocates a file before it needs it.  So 8GBs are occupying four 2GB files and one 2GB file is empty.

Now you do some pruning - maybe even 1.8GBs worth of deleting of stuff.  You run repairDB which rewrites every single record, as compactly as possible in a new set of database files.  Except it still needs the same five 2GB files because the fourth file has 100MB of data and the last file always has to be empty.

You can look at the output of db.stats() to see what the data size is compared to the storage size, but the fact is that these are relatively small numbers compared to the size of allocated files and that's likely why you are seeing what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks! I was using show dbs to give me the size. I figured that would be the size of the data not the size of the reserved files. Is there a way to determine the exact size of the data?

Comment: @DouglasFerguson As she says, `stats()` will tell you

Comment: try db.stats(1024*1024) <- number is multiplier so that you see results in MB instead of in bytes.

Comment: can you show db.stats for the other db (the copy you didn't delete from and repair)